# School crossing symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

Is there a package in LaTeX or TikZ that has the U.S. school crossing warning sign? An example is:

[image]

Comment: Why not include the image as a png?

Comment: I don't think so. Why don't you try to use `\includegraphics` in order to include an image as said?

Comment: I had a grey-background map and I didn't want to have the white border.

Comment: you can easily make the white background transparent with imagemagic or any image editor.

Comment: Why doesn't the edge of the road across from the people appear between their legs? Do they have some sort of yellow webbing between their legs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inkscape will convert to tikz:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{cf3d101}{RGB}{243,209,1}
\definecolor{c29241d}{RGB}{41,36,29}


\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
\begin{scope}[shift={(-246.61279,12.40819)}]
\path[fill=cf3d101,line width=0.212pt] (1.0822,8.5312) .. controls (0.9253,8.5123) and (0.8149,8.4210) .. (0.7753,8.2772) .. controls (0.7638,8.2356) and (0.7634,8.1902) .. (0.7634,6.8528) -- (0.7634,5.4713) -- (0.7770,5.4364) .. controls (0.7982,5.3821) and (0.8266,5.3330) .. (0.8632,5.2878) .. controls (0.9019,5.2400) and (3.7037,2.4394) .. (3.7522,2.4001) .. controls (3.7985,2.3626) and (3.8746,2.3268) .. (3.9275,2.3175) .. controls (3.9634,2.3113) and (3.9820,2.3113) .. (4.0208,2.3175) .. controls (4.0474,2.3218) and (4.0736,2.3278) .. (4.0790,2.3307) .. controls (4.0844,2.3337) and (4.1028,2.3422) .. (4.1198,2.3496) .. controls (4.1368,2.3570) and (4.1663,2.3743) .. (4.1854,2.3881) .. controls (4.2045,2.4018) and (4.8609,3.0534) .. (5.6441,3.8360) .. controls (6.6639,4.8549) and (7.0784,5.2730) .. (7.1043,5.3088) .. controls (7.1482,5.3696) and (7.1725,5.4202) .. (7.1838,5.4743) .. controls (7.1909,5.5081) and (7.1923,5.7459) .. (7.1922,6.8528) .. controls (7.1921,8.2685) and (7.1928,8.2313) .. (7.1640,8.3180) .. controls (7.1317,8.4152) and (7.0474,8.4882) .. (6.9298,8.5210) -- (6.8829,8.5340) -- (4.0013,8.5349) .. controls (2.4165,8.5353) and (1.1028,8.5337) .. (1.0822,8.5312) -- cycle;\path[fill=c29241d,line width=0.212pt] (1.0822,8.3815) .. controls (1.0095,8.3600) and (0.9592,8.3257) .. (0.9369,8.2825) .. controls (0.9303,8.2697) and (0.9195,8.2395) .. (0.9129,8.2154) .. controls (0.9013,8.1730) and (0.9009,8.1324) .. (0.9009,6.8496) .. controls (0.9009,5.5833) and (0.9014,5.5260) .. (0.9125,5.4901) .. controls (0.9188,5.4695) and (0.9334,5.4371) .. (0.9449,5.4182) .. controls (0.9596,5.3940) and (1.3888,4.9610) .. (2.3929,3.9574) .. controls (3.1778,3.1729) and (3.8308,2.5238) .. (3.8439,2.5150) .. controls (3.8733,2.4952) and (3.9052,2.4816) .. (3.9413,2.4735) .. controls (3.9969,2.4611) and (4.0782,2.4915) .. (4.1463,2.5502) .. controls (4.2249,2.6180) and (6.9877,5.3850) .. (7.0037,5.4119) .. controls (7.0241,5.4462) and (7.0352,5.4747) .. (7.0429,5.5125) .. controls (7.0465,5.5300) and (7.0481,6.0648) .. (7.0471,6.8783) -- (7.0455,8.2154) -- (7.0301,8.2529) .. controls (7.0113,8.2986) and (6.9627,8.3485) .. (6.9230,8.3629) .. controls (6.9078,8.3683) and (6.8856,8.3768) .. (6.8736,8.3816) .. controls (6.8549,8.3892) and (6.4365,8.3906) .. (3.9857,8.3916) .. controls (1.2555,8.3926) and (1.1179,8.3921) .. (1.0822,8.3815) -- cycle(6.8337,8.2226) .. controls (6.8512,8.2148) and (6.8643,8.2027) .. (6.8743,8.1851) -- (6.8892,8.1592) -- (6.8892,6.8403) -- (6.8892,5.5213) -- (6.8754,5.4932) .. controls (6.8651,5.4723) and (6.5389,5.1432) .. (5.6021,4.2087) .. controls (4.2155,2.8253) and (4.0471,2.6593) .. (4.0212,2.6495) .. controls (3.9986,2.6409) and (3.9505,2.6418) .. (3.9255,2.6512) .. controls (3.9129,2.6559) and (3.4039,3.1595) .. (2.4937,4.0680) .. controls (1.1142,5.4450) and (1.0813,5.4784) .. (1.0709,5.5120) .. controls (1.0609,5.5440) and (1.0603,5.6363) .. (1.0618,6.8559) .. controls (1.0634,8.1263) and (1.0638,8.1660) .. (1.0753,8.1849) .. controls (1.0883,8.2064) and (1.1150,8.2244) .. (1.1443,8.2315) .. controls (1.1548,8.2340) and (2.4335,8.2356) .. (3.9857,8.2351) .. controls (6.7181,8.2342) and (6.8088,8.2338) .. (6.8337,8.2226) -- cycle(1.4264,7.6432) .. controls (1.4139,7.6259) and (1.4054,7.6090) .. (1.4074,7.6057) .. controls (1.4118,7.5986) and (6.4041,7.5974) .. (6.4149,7.6045) .. controls (6.4273,7.6126) and (6.4665,7.6672) .. (6.4626,7.6710) .. controls (6.4606,7.6731) and (5.3317,7.6747) .. (3.9540,7.6747) -- (1.4491,7.6747) -- cycle(4.8893,7.2244) .. controls (4.8771,7.2036) and (4.8671,7.1852) .. (4.8671,7.1835) .. controls (4.8671,7.1818) and (4.8548,7.1588) .. (4.8399,7.1323) .. controls (4.8249,7.1057) and (4.7992,7.0587) .. (4.7828,7.0278) .. controls (4.7518,6.9693) and (4.7277,6.9248) .. (4.6983,6.8715) .. controls (4.6809,6.8399) and (4.6511,6.7843) .. (4.5997,6.6871) .. controls (4.5842,6.6579) and (4.5694,6.6312) .. (4.5669,6.6277) .. controls (4.5643,6.6243) and (4.5465,6.5905) .. (4.5272,6.5526) .. controls (4.4938,6.4870) and (4.4784,6.4368) .. (4.4606,6.3364) .. controls (4.4578,6.3206) and (4.4527,6.2966) .. (4.4491,6.2833) .. controls (4.4456,6.2699) and (4.4383,6.2378) .. (4.4329,6.2121) .. controls (4.4116,6.1099) and (4.4013,6.0729) .. (4.3934,6.0699) .. controls (4.3889,6.0682) and (4.3838,6.0681) .. (4.3821,6.0699) .. controls (4.3784,6.0736) and (4.3119,6.2334) .. (4.3048,6.2558) .. controls (4.3020,6.2644) and (4.2927,6.2869) .. (4.2841,6.3058) .. controls (4.2584,6.3622) and (4.2556,6.3741) .. (4.2483,6.4590) .. controls (4.2412,6.5403) and (4.2322,6.6378) .. (4.2140,6.8309) .. controls (4.2043,6.9334) and (4.1906,7.0789) .. (4.1822,7.1684) .. controls (4.1798,7.1942) and (4.1750,7.2188) .. (4.1716,7.2231) .. controls (4.1643,7.2324) and (4.1122,7.2334) .. (4.0802,7.2249) .. controls (4.0678,7.2216) and (4.0364,7.2172) .. (4.0104,7.2151) .. controls (3.9845,7.2130) and (3.9599,7.2093) .. (3.9557,7.2067) .. controls (3.9480,7.2020) and (3.9516,7.0894) .. (3.9667,6.8621) .. controls (3.9732,6.7645) and (3.9861,6.5472) .. (3.9985,6.3277) -- (4.0052,6.2089) -- (4.0490,6.0714) .. controls (4.0731,5.9958) and (4.0954,5.9290) .. (4.0986,5.9230) .. controls (4.1018,5.9171) and (4.1045,5.9072) .. (4.1045,5.9012) .. controls (4.1045,5.8951) and (4.1088,5.8821) .. (4.1139,5.8722) .. controls (4.1190,5.8624) and (4.1232,5.8497) .. (4.1233,5.8441) .. controls (4.1233,5.8385) and (4.1275,5.8258) .. (4.1326,5.8160) .. controls (4.1378,5.8061) and (4.1420,5.7935) .. (4.1420,5.7879) .. controls (4.1420,5.7822) and (4.1463,5.7696) .. (4.1514,5.7597) .. controls (4.1565,5.7499) and (4.1607,5.7386) .. (4.1607,5.7347) .. controls (4.1607,5.7308) and (4.1725,5.6919) .. (4.1869,5.6481) .. controls (4.2130,5.5686) and (4.2131,5.5684) .. (4.2051,5.5262) .. controls (4.1975,5.4859) and (4.1896,5.4516) .. (4.1700,5.3745) .. controls (4.1652,5.3555) and (4.1568,5.3190) .. (4.1513,5.2932) .. controls (4.1367,5.2250) and (4.1222,5.1611) .. (4.1172,5.1432) .. controls (4.1118,5.1239) and (4.0875,5.1182) .. (4.0818,5.1349) .. controls (4.0668,5.1790) and (4.0340,5.2379) .. (4.0217,5.2430) .. controls (4.0139,5.2462) and (3.9696,5.2604) .. (3.9232,5.2746) .. controls (3.8768,5.2888) and (3.8205,5.3061) .. (3.7982,5.3129) .. controls (3.7230,5.3361) and (3.7076,5.3454) .. (3.6994,5.3730) .. controls (3.6855,5.4193) and (3.6861,5.4201) .. (3.7349,5.4209) -- (3.7623,5.4213) -- (3.7742,5.4745) .. controls (3.7808,5.5037) and (3.7904,5.5487) .. (3.7955,5.5745) .. controls (3.8007,5.6003) and (3.8090,5.6396) .. (3.8141,5.6620) .. controls (3.8246,5.7082) and (3.8254,5.7224) .. (3.8180,5.7270) .. controls (3.8121,5.7306) and (3.7575,5.7415) .. (3.6419,5.7621) .. controls (3.5438,5.7795) and (3.5184,5.7858) .. (3.5136,5.7935) .. controls (3.5100,5.7994) and (3.5447,5.9083) .. (3.5544,5.9214) .. controls (3.5569,5.9248) and (3.5648,5.9445) .. (3.5718,5.9652) .. controls (3.5789,5.9858) and (3.5907,6.0167) .. (3.5982,6.0339) .. controls (3.6282,6.1035) and (3.6430,6.1521) .. (3.6379,6.1652) .. controls (3.6352,6.1724) and (3.6206,6.1797) .. (3.5607,6.2038) .. controls (3.5267,6.2175) and (3.5202,6.2220) .. (3.5180,6.2331) .. controls (3.5163,6.2415) and (3.5782,6.4465) .. (3.6050,6.5215) .. controls (3.6087,6.5318) and (3.6141,6.5487) .. (3.6169,6.5590) .. controls (3.6235,6.5831) and (3.6350,6.6160) .. (3.6459,6.6420) .. controls (3.6506,6.6533) and (3.6544,6.6674) .. (3.6545,6.6733) .. controls (3.6545,6.6792) and (3.6587,6.6921) .. (3.6638,6.7019) .. controls (3.6690,6.7117) and (3.6732,6.7240) .. (3.6732,6.7291) .. controls (3.6732,6.7342) and (3.6769,6.7472) .. (3.6815,6.7581) .. controls (3.6950,6.7900) and (3.7053,6.8200) .. (3.7107,6.8434) .. controls (3.7134,6.8554) and (3.7192,6.8751) .. (3.7234,6.8871) .. controls (3.7277,6.8992) and (3.7346,6.9189) .. (3.7388,6.9309) .. controls (3.7430,6.9429) and (3.7499,6.9626) .. (3.7543,6.9747) .. controls (3.7670,7.0102) and (3.7686,7.0280) .. (3.7596,7.0351) .. controls (3.7512,7.0417) and (3.6674,7.0747) .. (3.6589,7.0747) .. controls (3.6563,7.0747) and (3.6471,7.0585) .. (3.6383,7.0387) .. controls (3.6296,7.0190) and (3.6200,6.9972) .. (3.6169,6.9903) .. controls (3.6138,6.9834) and (3.6054,6.9637) .. (3.5982,6.9465) .. controls (3.5909,6.9293) and (3.5825,6.9096) .. (3.5794,6.9028) .. controls (3.5763,6.8959) and (3.5679,6.8762) .. (3.5605,6.8590) .. controls (3.5532,6.8418) and (3.5430,6.8179) .. (3.5379,6.8059) .. controls (3.5328,6.7939) and (3.5263,6.7784) .. (3.5235,6.7715) .. controls (3.5207,6.7646) and (3.5097,6.7401) .. (3.4989,6.7169) .. controls (3.4882,6.6938) and (3.4794,6.6717) .. (3.4794,6.6679) .. controls (3.4794,6.6641) and (3.4754,6.6535) .. (3.4704,6.6443) .. controls (3.4542,6.6141) and (3.4231,6.5434) .. (3.4231,6.5365) .. controls (3.4231,6.5327) and (3.4191,6.5222) .. (3.4142,6.5131) .. controls (3.3979,6.4829) and (3.3669,6.4122) .. (3.3669,6.4052) .. controls (3.3669,6.4015) and (3.3629,6.3909) .. (3.3579,6.3818) .. controls (3.3530,6.3727) and (3.3403,6.3455) .. (3.3297,6.3214) .. controls (3.3190,6.2974) and (3.3080,6.2735) .. (3.3051,6.2683) .. controls (3.2978,6.2550) and (3.1571,6.2472) .. (3.1382,6.2591) .. controls (3.1301,6.2642) and (3.1186,6.2868) .. (3.1076,6.3193) .. controls (3.0979,6.3480) and (3.0845,6.3841) .. (3.0778,6.3996) .. controls (3.0711,6.4151) and (3.0591,6.4474) .. (3.0512,6.4715) .. controls (3.0371,6.5140) and (3.0305,6.5314) .. (3.0128,6.5724) .. controls (3.0082,6.5833) and (3.0043,6.5965) .. (3.0043,6.6017) .. controls (3.0043,6.6070) and (3.0018,6.6129) .. (2.9988,6.6148) .. controls (2.9957,6.6167) and (2.9914,6.6260) .. (2.9891,6.6355) .. controls (2.9849,6.6530) and (2.9592,6.7247) .. (2.9448,6.7590) .. controls (2.9405,6.7693) and (2.9123,6.8444) .. (2.8822,6.9259) .. controls (2.8521,7.0074) and (2.8234,7.0756) .. (2.8186,7.0774) .. controls (2.8137,7.0793) and (2.8022,7.0770) .. (2.7930,7.0724) .. controls (2.7837,7.0677) and (2.7688,7.0622) .. (2.7598,7.0600) .. controls (2.7508,7.0578) and (2.7368,7.0508) .. (2.7289,7.0443) -- (2.7143,7.0325) -- (2.7254,6.9927) .. controls (2.7315,6.9707) and (2.7407,6.9359) .. (2.7458,6.9153) .. controls (2.7509,6.8946) and (2.7575,6.8693) .. (2.7604,6.8590) .. controls (2.7633,6.8487) and (2.7717,6.8178) .. (2.7791,6.7903) .. controls (2.7864,6.7628) and (2.7963,6.7262) .. (2.8009,6.7090) .. controls (2.8227,6.6287) and (2.8291,6.6046) .. (2.8447,6.5434) .. controls (2.8539,6.5073) and (2.8668,6.4601) .. (2.8735,6.4385) .. controls (2.8801,6.4170) and (2.8856,6.3936) .. (2.8856,6.3865) .. controls (2.8856,6.3795) and (2.8884,6.3684) .. (2.8920,6.3618) .. controls (2.8955,6.3553) and (2.9011,6.3365) .. (2.9044,6.3201) .. controls (2.9077,6.3036) and (2.9160,6.2705) .. (2.9227,6.2464) .. controls (2.9336,6.2075) and (2.9339,6.2011) .. (2.9257,6.1886) .. controls (2.9207,6.1809) and (2.9116,6.1746) .. (2.9056,6.1746) .. controls (2.8846,6.1746) and (2.8668,6.1563) .. (2.8668,6.1348) .. controls (2.8668,6.1237) and (2.8699,6.1115) .. (2.8736,6.1078) .. controls (2.8773,6.1041) and (2.8827,6.0916) .. (2.8857,6.0800) .. controls (2.8886,6.0684) and (2.9007,6.0322) .. (2.9124,5.9995) .. controls (2.9242,5.9669) and (2.9401,5.9219) .. (2.9477,5.8995) .. controls (2.9553,5.8772) and (2.9640,5.8533) .. (2.9671,5.8464) .. controls (2.9733,5.8326) and (2.9807,5.8117) .. (3.0170,5.7057) .. controls (3.0472,5.6173) and (3.0565,5.5919) .. (3.0614,5.5839) .. controls (3.0635,5.5804) and (3.0688,5.5635) .. (3.0731,5.5462) .. controls (3.0803,5.5174) and (3.0796,5.5103) .. (3.0642,5.4587) .. controls (3.0436,5.3900) and (3.0407,5.3843) .. (3.0247,5.3819) .. controls (3.0136,5.3803) and (3.0091,5.3892) .. (2.9887,5.4538) .. controls (2.9626,5.5360) and (2.9638,5.5346) .. (2.8793,5.5924) .. controls (2.8501,5.6124) and (2.8085,5.6412) .. (2.7868,5.6563) .. controls (2.7652,5.6715) and (2.7428,5.6867) .. (2.7372,5.6901) .. controls (2.7315,5.6936) and (2.7103,5.7083) .. (2.6899,5.7229) .. controls (2.6696,5.7375) and (2.6477,5.7495) .. (2.6414,5.7495) .. controls (2.6306,5.7495) and (2.6138,5.7311) .. (2.5886,5.6914) -- (2.5774,5.6739) -- (2.7117,5.5382) .. controls (2.8508,5.3976) and (2.8668,5.3786) .. (2.8668,5.3540) .. controls (2.8668,5.3459) and (2.8709,5.3339) .. (2.8760,5.3272) .. controls (2.8810,5.3205) and (2.8854,5.3080) .. (2.8856,5.2994) .. controls (2.8858,5.2909) and (2.8901,5.2784) .. (2.8951,5.2717) .. controls (2.9002,5.2650) and (2.9043,5.2546) .. (2.9043,5.2485) .. controls (2.9043,5.2424) and (2.9082,5.2281) .. (2.9129,5.2168) .. controls (2.9233,5.1920) and (2.9348,5.1591) .. (2.9420,5.1338) .. controls (2.9523,5.0979) and (3.0083,4.9399) .. (3.0152,4.9275) .. controls (3.0189,4.9206) and (3.0514,4.8862) .. (3.0873,4.8510) -- (3.1525,4.7869) -- (3.1988,4.7869) .. controls (3.2278,4.7869) and (3.2617,4.7820) .. (3.2899,4.7736) -- (3.3348,4.7603) -- (3.4368,4.8241) .. controls (3.5226,4.8777) and (3.5405,4.8915) .. (3.5497,4.9113) .. controls (3.5557,4.9242) and (3.5607,4.9366) .. (3.5607,4.9389) .. controls (3.5607,4.9430) and (3.5937,5.0176) .. (3.6043,5.0375) .. controls (3.6072,5.0430) and (3.6214,5.0754) .. (3.6358,5.1094) .. controls (3.6636,5.1751) and (3.6755,5.1932) .. (3.6909,5.1932) .. controls (3.7049,5.1932) and (3.9449,5.0766) .. (3.9539,5.0655) .. controls (3.9593,5.0588) and (3.9718,5.0187) .. (4.0045,4.9025) .. controls (4.0142,4.8681) and (4.0308,4.8098) .. (4.0414,4.7728) .. controls (4.0846,4.6224) and (4.0994,4.5702) .. (4.1044,4.5505) .. controls (4.1096,4.5298) and (4.1582,4.4804) .. (4.2110,4.4422) .. controls (4.2384,4.4223) and (4.2429,4.4162) .. (4.2516,4.3868) .. controls (4.2578,4.3657) and (4.2597,4.3646) .. (4.3047,4.3550) .. controls (4.3570,4.3439) and (4.3841,4.3316) .. (4.4071,4.3087) .. controls (4.4252,4.2905) and (4.4470,4.2883) .. (4.4524,4.3040) .. controls (4.4681,4.3506) and (4.4767,4.3623) .. (4.5042,4.3750) .. controls (4.5540,4.3978) and (4.5694,4.4044) .. (4.6045,4.4179) .. controls (4.6234,4.4251) and (4.6451,4.4358) .. (4.6526,4.4417) .. controls (4.6602,4.4476) and (4.6851,4.4890) .. (4.7080,4.5337) .. controls (4.7310,4.5784) and (4.7617,4.6375) .. (4.7763,4.6650) .. controls (4.9243,4.9428) and (4.9741,5.0442) .. (4.9709,5.0612) .. controls (4.9477,5.1864) and (4.9413,5.2324) .. (4.9466,5.2377) .. controls (4.9504,5.2415) and (4.9625,5.2412) .. (4.9801,5.2368) .. controls (4.9953,5.2329) and (5.0140,5.2283) .. (5.0217,5.2264) .. controls (5.0304,5.2243) and (5.0367,5.2262) .. (5.0385,5.2315) .. controls (5.0400,5.2362) and (5.0542,5.2823) .. (5.0699,5.3338) .. controls (5.0857,5.3854) and (5.1015,5.4360) .. (5.1051,5.4463) .. controls (5.1087,5.4567) and (5.1158,5.4792) .. (5.1209,5.4963) .. controls (5.1260,5.5135) and (5.1330,5.5374) .. (5.1366,5.5495) .. controls (5.1509,5.5977) and (5.1571,5.5927) .. (5.0390,5.6278) .. controls (5.0218,5.6329) and (4.9796,5.6456) .. (4.9452,5.6560) .. controls (4.8825,5.6749) and (4.8494,5.6849) .. (4.7998,5.6998) .. controls (4.7851,5.7042) and (4.7702,5.7114) .. (4.7666,5.7157) .. controls (4.7629,5.7202) and (4.7576,5.7839) .. (4.7544,5.8631) .. controls (4.7513,5.9399) and (4.7473,6.0196) .. (4.7454,6.0402) .. controls (4.7435,6.0609) and (4.7392,6.1409) .. (4.7358,6.2179) -- (4.7296,6.3579) -- (4.7461,6.3928) .. controls (4.7552,6.4120) and (4.8058,6.5160) .. (4.8586,6.6238) .. controls (4.9114,6.7317) and (4.9546,6.8213) .. (4.9546,6.8229) .. controls (4.9546,6.8246) and (4.9871,6.8925) .. (5.0269,6.9737) .. controls (5.0666,7.0550) and (5.1022,7.1277) .. (5.1058,7.1352) .. controls (5.1095,7.1427) and (5.1110,7.1527) .. (5.1092,7.1574) .. controls (5.1074,7.1622) and (5.0669,7.1853) .. (5.0193,7.2088) .. controls (4.9717,7.2324) and (4.9279,7.2540) .. (4.9221,7.2570) .. controls (4.9135,7.2613) and (4.9073,7.2551) .. (4.8893,7.2244) -- cycle(3.4877,5.4704) .. controls (3.5083,5.4670) and (3.5133,5.4628) .. (3.5230,5.4407) .. controls (3.5412,5.3993) and (3.5545,5.3540) .. (3.5543,5.3338) .. controls (3.5542,5.3111) and (3.5244,5.2502) .. (3.5087,5.2407) .. controls (3.4910,5.2299) and (3.4847,5.2442) .. (3.4583,5.3550) .. controls (3.4292,5.4769) and (3.4300,5.4799) .. (3.4877,5.4704) -- cycle(4.7573,5.3031) .. controls (4.7763,5.2952) and (4.7791,5.2907) .. (4.7855,5.2578) .. controls (4.7894,5.2377) and (4.7953,5.2090) .. (4.7987,5.1940) .. controls (4.8021,5.1790) and (4.8065,5.1509) .. (4.8085,5.1315) -- (4.8121,5.0963) -- (4.7363,4.9947) .. controls (4.6946,4.9389) and (4.6561,4.8931) .. (4.6508,4.8931) .. controls (4.6426,4.8931) and (4.6415,4.8999) .. (4.6442,4.9353) .. controls (4.6475,4.9792) and (4.6501,4.9962) .. (4.6729,5.1213) .. controls (4.6804,5.1626) and (4.6904,5.2200) .. (4.6952,5.2489) .. controls (4.7060,5.3139) and (4.7142,5.3211) .. (4.7573,5.3031) -- cycle(1.4510,6.4636) .. controls (1.4362,6.4527) and (1.4038,6.4052) .. (1.4073,6.3995) .. controls (1.4098,6.3955) and (1.6500,6.3933) .. (2.0959,6.3933) -- (2.7807,6.3933) -- (2.7764,6.4223) .. controls (2.7740,6.4382) and (2.7706,6.4550) .. (2.7688,6.4598) .. controls (2.7660,6.4670) and (2.6600,6.4683) .. (2.1114,6.4682) .. controls (1.7516,6.4682) and (1.4545,6.4661) .. (1.4510,6.4636) -- cycle(3.6772,6.4417) .. controls (3.6578,6.3909) and (3.6527,6.3933) .. (3.7793,6.3933) -- (3.8917,6.3933) -- (3.8954,6.4081) .. controls (3.8974,6.4162) and (3.8982,6.4324) .. (3.8971,6.4440) -- (3.8951,6.4652) -- (3.7913,6.4669) -- (3.6875,6.4686) -- cycle(4.8701,6.4369) .. controls (4.8613,6.4195) and (4.8558,6.4027) .. (4.8578,6.3993) .. controls (4.8602,6.3955) and (5.1477,6.3933) .. (5.6392,6.3933) -- (6.4169,6.3933) -- (6.4421,6.4274) .. controls (6.4559,6.4462) and (6.4673,6.4631) .. (6.4673,6.4649) .. controls (6.4673,6.4668) and (6.1115,6.4683) .. (5.6766,6.4683) -- (4.8860,6.4683) -- cycle(3.1356,4.7373) .. controls (3.1167,4.7314) and (3.0916,4.7215) .. (3.0799,4.7154) .. controls (3.0542,4.7020) and (2.9981,4.6505) .. (2.9981,4.6404) .. controls (2.9981,4.6364) and (2.9949,4.6299) .. (2.9909,4.6260) .. controls (2.9762,4.6112) and (2.9606,4.5523) .. (2.9606,4.5116) .. controls (2.9606,4.3553) and (3.1123,4.2402) .. (3.2604,4.2842) .. controls (3.3415,4.3083) and (3.3928,4.3579) .. (3.4214,4.4400) .. controls (3.4384,4.4885) and (3.4391,4.5306) .. (3.4238,4.5785) .. controls (3.3965,4.6639) and (3.3448,4.7122) .. (3.2535,4.7375) .. controls (3.2022,4.7517) and (3.1809,4.7517) .. (3.1356,4.7373) -- cycle(4.1701,4.3034) .. controls (4.1039,4.2812) and (4.0476,4.2321) .. (4.0158,4.1687) .. controls (3.9959,4.1291) and (3.9951,4.1245) .. (3.9951,4.0555) .. controls (3.9951,3.9897) and (3.9965,3.9807) .. (4.0124,3.9485) .. controls (4.0781,3.8147) and (4.2315,3.7615) .. (4.3655,3.8260) .. controls (4.4507,3.8670) and (4.5073,3.9605) .. (4.5065,4.0587) .. controls (4.5059,4.1166) and (4.4928,4.1556) .. (4.4551,4.2107) .. controls (4.4204,4.2614) and (4.3969,4.2813) .. (4.3560,4.2947) .. controls (4.3093,4.3101) and (4.2046,4.3150) .. (4.1701,4.3034) -- cycle;\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's pretty amazing.

Answer (score -1):

Gimp will remove background, then includegraphic is possible even with gray background

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/188482)

Comment: While it is not a great answer, it definitely does answer the question, so I voted to undelete.

Comment: In dark mode it looks as if the cutting at the edges isn't very precise, though.